# Check two fields no repeat in table when MySQL INSERT

Tags: mysql

I have following table:

```
     table (id,
            longitude,
            latitude,
            longlat,
            address,
            description,
            kind,
            synonym,
            primary key(id)
      );
```

I need to check that fields `longlat` and `description` in inserting row are unique and there are no rows with **same combination** of `longlat` and `description` it the table, inserted before it.

How should I modify my query?

```
      "INSERT INTO yandex_social_objects (longitude,latitude,longlat,address,description,kind,synonym) VALUES (val_1),(val_2),(val_3)...(val_n)"
```

Comment: Possibly easiest to just add a  unique key on those fields to the table

Comment: yeah create a unique combination of both longlat & description

Comment: But what if I try to insert another row, where `longlat` will be duplicate and `decription` - not? whether this row is inserted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the combination so this never happens:

```
ALTER TABLE yandex_social_objects
  ADD CONSTRAINT longlat_description_UQ
    UNIQUE (longlat, description) ;
```

After that, all your Inserts into the table will check this combination for uniqueness and either succeed or fail.

You can use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` for different behaviour on unique key collisions. Check this answer for differences: [`INSERT IGNORE` vs `INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: I have an error `Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes` with your query. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, I guess the `description` or the `longlat` is too long. What are the datatypes?

Comment: `longlat` is varcar(128) and `description` is varchar(256)

Comment: And is the table using InnoDB or MyISAM engine?

Comment: You'll have to lower the length. I suppose you have InnoDB, so a change of the 256 to 255 will be enough.

Comment: now there are now errors with your query now but if I try to insert duplicate value I get mysql error. How to modify insert-query to just ignore repeating row?

Comment: You can use INSERT IGNORE - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update